# Is there a maximum length of the chief series of $SL(n,q)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

### Motivation:

I'm studying certain properties of conjugation in $SL(n,q)$. There's a nice number, a bit like a covering number, that one can associate with an arbitrary group. In writing a programme in GAP to compute this number, a shortcut comes to mind - I'm not going to share what exactly - that involves the [chief series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series) of the groups.

### The Question:

> What, if anything, is the maximum length of the chief series of $SL(n,q)$?

### Thoughts:

I ran the following in GAP:

```
for n in [2..6] do
   for q in Filtered([2..11],IsPrime) do
         Print([n,q,Size(ChiefSeries(SL(n,q)))],"\n");
   od;
od;
```

It produced . . .

```
[ 2, 2, 3 ]
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 5, 3 ]
[ 2, 7, 3 ]
[ 2, 11, 3 ]
[ 3, 2, 2 ]
[ 3, 3, 2 ]
[ 3, 5, 2 ]
[ 3, 7, 3 ]
[ 3, 11, 2 ]
[ 4, 2, 2 ]
[ 4, 3, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 4 ]
[ 4, 7, 3 ]
[ 4, 11, 3 ]
[ 5, 2, 2 ]
[ 5, 3, 2 ]
[ 5, 5, 2 ]
[ 5, 7, 2 ]
```

. . . after which I terminated the calculation.

As you can see, the maximum length calculated is $4$ and is obtained by both $SL(2,3)$ and $SL(4,5)$. This is very little to go by, of course.

*What do I think it would be?*

I'd be pleasantly surprised if the maximum existed.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, $PSL(n,q)$ is usually simple, so apart from  $SL(2,3)$ you're looking at two plus the number of prime factors, counting multiplicity, of the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $q-1$. Of course, this is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveBenson. I don't believe we have met. I'm in your department; Prof. Martin's student. I think I saw you during a research seminar back in March.

Comment: Ha! Hello Shaun! If you want a proof of the intuitively plausible fact that the number of prime factors of $p-1$ is unbounded, Halberstam's paper "On the distribution of additive number-theoretic functions. III." MR0073627 is the place to go.

Comment: And actually for this particular fact rather than his more general theorem he refers to a paper of Erdös from 1935, showing that the number of prime factors grows like log log $p$.

Comment: You can also use Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression for existence. Take an integer $m$ with any chosen number of different prime factors, and ther are infinitely many primes $p$ which are congruent to $1$ (mod $m$).